# Loop Through files in a folder and paste filename onto spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am totally new to VBA, looking for tips or hints to solve this question.

I am trying to loop through all the files in a folder and trying to split the filename into three parts that are separated by underscore and then paste those into a spreadsheet. After that, pivot it and count how many files there are in a new sheet.

For example, Filename : CA_File_20170810.txt

So it looks like this:

```
**IPA       TYPE       DATE         Filename     Filepath**     
   CA      File       20170810
```

*IPA, Type, Date,filename, filepath are columns headers in excel.

Here is what I have in my code so far

```
Sub LoopingThroughFiles()

Dim f As String
Dim G As String
Dim File As Variant
Dim MyObj As Object
Dim MySource As Object
Dim FileName As Variant
Dim TypeName As Variant

Cells(1, 1) = "IPA"
Cells(1, 2) = "TYPE"
Cells(1, 3) = "DATE"
Cells(1, 4) = "FILENAME"
Cells(1, 5) = "FILEPATH"
Cells(2, 1).Select

f = Dir("C:\Users\kxc8574\Documents\VBA_Practice\")
G = Dir("C:\Users\kxc8574\Documents\VBA_Practice\")

If Right(f, 1) <> "\" Then
f = f + "\"




Cells(2, 1).Select

Do While Len(f) > 0
IpaName = Left(f, InStr(f, "_") - 1)
ActiveCell.Formula = IpaName
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
f = Dir()
Loop
Do While Len(G) > 0
TypeName = Mid(G, InStr(G, "_") + 1, InStr(G, "File_") - InStr(G, "_") - 1)
ActiveCell.Formula = TypeName
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
G = Dir()

Loop


End If
End Sub
```

I am missing a lot of things, not sure how to really continue. This code gives me an error "invalid procedure call" when it reaches the G = Dir()

Thanks for your help !!!

Comment: Hi Kevin, if you could give a little more info on exactly what "the code gives me" and what you are looking for, I am sure you will get a response soon.

Answer (score 1):

First, paste the text under "Explanation" into A1 of a worksheet.  Then paste the code under "Code" into a module.  Make sure the workbook is in the same directory as your .txt files.  Then, run the macro.  See animated gif for the result.

"Explanation"

```
This workbook contains a macro which will
1) Make a new sheet in this workbook named "Combined"
2) Open a copy of each .txt file located in the same directory as this workbook
3) extract the text between "_" characters
4) place the separated text into columns
5) count the number of .txt files processed
Note: Any sheet named "Combined" in this Workbook will be deleted
```

"Code"

```
Option Explicit
Sub CombineFiles()
Dim theDir As String, theFile As String
Dim sh As Worksheet, wk As Workbook, newSheet As Worksheet
Dim r As Range, parts() As String
Dim i As Long, s As String
Dim Done As Boolean, numFiles As Integer
Const ext = ".txt"
    Err.Clear
    theDir = ThisWorkbook.Path
    'explain what program does
    Worksheets("Program").Select
    For i = 1 To 7
    s = s & Cells(i, 1) & vbCr & vbCr
    Next i
    s = s & vbCr
    s = MsgBox(s, vbYesNoCancel, "What this macro does")
    If s <> vbYes Then End
    For Each sh In Worksheets
        If sh.Name = "Combined" Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            sh.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next
    Set newSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    newSheet.Name = "Combined"
    'Loop through all files in directory with ext
    s = Dir(theDir & "\*" & ext)
    Set r = Range("A1")
    r = "IPA"
    r.Offset(0, 1) = "Type"
    r.Offset(0, 2) = "Date"
    r.Offset(0, 3) = "filename"
    r.Offset(0, 4) = "filepath"
    While s <> ""
        numFiles = numFiles + 1
        parts = Split(s, "_")
        Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
        For i = 0 To 2
        r.Offset(, i) = Replace(parts(i), ".txt", "")
        Next i
        r.Offset(, 3) = s
        r.Offset(, 4) = theDir & "\" & s & ext
        s = Dir()
    Wend
    MsgBox (numFiles & " files were processed.")
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Untested but should give you some idea:

```
Sub LoopingThroughFiles()

    Const FPATH As String = "C:\Users\kxc8574\Documents\VBA_Practice\"

    Dim f As String, i As Long, arr, sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    sht.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 5).Value = _
                Array("IPA", "TYPE", "DATE", "FILENAME", "FILEPATH")

    f = Dir(FPATH & "*.txt") '<< only txt files
    i = 2
    Do While f <> ""
        'split filename on underscore after replacing the ".txt"
        arr = Split(Replace(f, ".txt", ""), "_", 3)
        sht.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1).Value = arr
        sht.Cells(i, 4).Value = f
        sht.Cells(i, 5).Value = FPATH
        f = Dir() '<< next file
        i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested but perhaps something like this??

```
Sub HashFiles()
    Dim MyDir As String, MyIPA As Variant, MyType As Variant, MyDate As Variant, i As Integer, oFile As Object, oFSO As Object, oFolder As Object, oFiles As Object
    MyDir = "C:\Users\kxc8574\Documents\VBA_Practice\"
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(MyDir)
    Set oFiles = oFolder.Files
    ReDim MyIPA(1 To oFiles.Count)
    ReDim MyType(1 To oFiles.Count)
    ReDim MyDate(1 To oFiles.Count)
    i = 1
    For Each oFile In oFiles
        MyIPA(i) = Split(oFile.Name, "_")(0)
        MyType(i) = Split(oFile.Name, "_")(1)
        MyDate(i) = Split(oFile.Name, "_")(2)
        i = i + 1
    Next
    Range("A2").Resize(UBound(MyIPA) + 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(MyIPA)
    Range("B2").Resize(UBound(MyType) + 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(MyType)
    Range("C2").Resize(UBound(MyDate) + 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(MyDate)
End Sub
```